# How to perform bit operation on a multidimensional char array in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, bitwise-operators

I have the following multidimensional char array. I need to first `XOR` one of the arrays with the mask array and then `AND` the result with the other array. What is the fastest way to implement it?

Note: the char arrays can be as large as 20 KB in size.

```
unsigned char test1[2][2] = { { 'a','b' },{ 0 } };
unsigned char test2[2][2] = { { 0 },{ 'O','S' } };
unsigned char mask[2][2] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that the values in the test array are always ANDed with the mask? Does mask change?

Comment: mask never changes@Gerhardh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that may be fast:

```
int cnt = sizeof(mask)/sizeof(unsigned char)

while(cnt>0)
{
    *((unsigned char*)test1+cnt) ^= *((unsigned char*)mask+cnt);
    *((unsigned char*)test1+cnt) &= *((unsigned char*)test2+cnt);
    cnt--;
}
```

There is only one time the way through the arrays and you move only 3 pointer wich may be well optimized by the compiler. To be MOST efficient, we must do some tests and see the assembly output. IT also depends on the architecture you use (X86, ARM, AVR, PIC, ...)

Comment: @George: For being faster it is necessary to load the greatest integer that can your register hold (architecture dependend) instead of load a character. Read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21336509/8051589.

Comment: The XOR does not really work. The value of test1 remains the same after the operation. I also tried to assign the XOR result on another array, still the same result, the XOR operation does not work. @AndreKampling

Comment: @George what is the value of mask ? with 0 as in the example, XOR does nothing.

Comment: I am trying to identify the number of bit positions where there are 0s in test1 and 1s in corresponding positions in test2. so i have to perform the XOR on test1 with mask  in order to toggle those 0 positions. @Julien

Comment: @George If my understanding is correct you search for `(NOT test1) AND test2` try `~` instead of  `^`. Because with `mask=0`, `anything XOR mask == anything`.

Comment: Thanks@Julien. ~ does solve my problem. I was trying to solve my problem  the wrong way.